# Can anyone recommend a 3D model viewer with shading?

Tags: opengl, shaders

I am looking for a simple real-time OpenGL based render engine to show a 3D model on screen.

I prefer using 3DS Max's 'shader' materials (real-time materials) for editing.

Do you know any good simple API to include it in an OpenGL screen? Is there a simple tool to export from 3DS Max to that tool?

Answer (score 2):

[Blender](http://www.blender.org/) supports OpenGL shading, but I don't know how the material conversion is when you export to a .obj or .fbx file.

You could also try [Unity3D](http://unity3d.com/). This one is free as well and can import your 3ds max files on the fly (but still convert them to FBX internally). You can let Unity3D emulate OpenGL if you want.

Or if it could also be DirextX, you could also search for [3ds max directx render](http://www.google.com/search?q=3ds+max+directx+render). There doesn't seem to be much support for that, but maybe you can find the appropriate way to view your materials that way.

Answer (score 0):

I think RenderMonkey is what you're looking for. Realtime rendering, ideal for shader development. but i am afraid i misunderstood the question.
Sorry if that is the case.

Answer (score 0):

http://xoliulshader.com/

This is on of the best real-time viewport-shaders I know of.

It's widely used and you can see its free and looks mighty fine. It's just a new material in Max. It's popular among forums like polycount and a lot of artists use it to create renders.

edit: So it might be a good idea to look at the source ;)